# AutoFill simulation

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a simulation to find out the number of trials needed to run before a success is found. This is my sample idea of how it is going to work. Column A contains a simple formula `=A1+1` (which means previous row +1). The simulation should end when the value reaches `10`.

```
Sub RunEX25()  
A = 1  
B = 1  
Do While True  
     Count = Count + 1
     Range("A2").Select  
     Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(Count, A), Cells(Count, B)), Type:=xlFillDefault
     Cells(Count, A).Select  
     If Cells(Count, A).Value = 10 Then  
         Exit Do  
     End If  
Loop
```

The problem when I run this code is that error 1004 pops out.

Can anyone help me rectify this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This does not make sense to me.

Comment: Have you tried the answer provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs several improvements, but this line:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(Count, A), Cells(Count, B)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

in particular is the one giving the error 1004.

At this point the `Selection` range is cell `A2` however the `Destination` range is `A1` and the [Range.AutoFill Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345(v=office.15).aspx) specifically says:

> The destination must include the source range.

Correct this line but also it's suggested:

- A complete debug of the code
- Declare all your variables
- Avoid the use of the Select method